# conditional formatting from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet that has a list of computers (sheet 1 column A) with locations (sheet 1 column B) in it.  Part of the checks being done is to put in column C when the computer was checked or touched.  In sheet 2 we have a list of locations (Say cubical 1, 2, 3, etc).  Basically, what we are doing in sheet 2 is to check if sheet 1 column B (locations) has a a specific value listed somewhere in it (IE "Cubical 1"), then look in the row that "Cubical 1" is in to see if the date in column C was within the last 90 days.  If it's not, then it highlights the cell in sheet 2 in red.

Anyone know how this can be achieved?  I know how to check for the date and see if it's within the last 90 days, what I dont know how to do is check if a location is listed in a column, then check the row that value is in (if it's there) to see that date to do the 90 day check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the VLOOKUP function.

```
VLOOKUP("location",Sheet2!B1:B25,3,FALSE)
```

Will look for "location" on Sheet2 between cell B1 and B25 and return the 3rd cell's data (assuming that's where the date is located) from the row where the match is found. FALSE means the match must be exact.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question correctly. Below is my illustration:

**Sheet 1**
you know how to fill in WITHIN_90DAYS; and formula for FAILED_KEY is straightforward:

=IF(D2="Y", "", B2)

```
COMPUTER | LOCATION | DATE_CHECKED | WITHIN_90DAYS? | FAILED_KEY
00000001 | Cubical1 | 2013-01-30   | Y              | 
00000002 | Cubical1 | 2012-11-30   | N              | Cubical1
00000003 | Cubical2 | 2012-05-30   | N              | Cubical2
00000004 | Cubical2 | 2012-05-31   | N              | Cubical2
00000005 | Cubical3 | 2013-03-21   | Y              |
```

**Sheet 2** (FAILED_COUNT column is easy using a simple COUNTIF)

```
LOCATION | FAILED_COUNT
Cubical1 | 1
Cubical2 | 2
Cubical3 | 0
```

And then you can apply conditional formatting according to the column "FAILED_COUNT"

Answer (score 1):

1. In Sheet1 name ColumnB:C, say Loc_Date (to create a worksheet name range that can be used as part of CF in a different sheet).
2. In Sheet2 select locations column, Home > Styles – Conditional Formatting, select New Rule / Use a Formula to determine which cells to format and in Format values where this formula is true enter:
3. `=NOW()-VLOOKUP(A1,Loc_Date,2,FALSE)-90>0`
4. Click Format, Fill and select red, OK.